# How to encrypt user form information in Laravel

Tags: laravel, encryption

How to encrypt the information sent by the user to the Store method controller in Laravel and use the information there?

i have a form like this inputes

```
#parameters: array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "TSxHdqBCiuikJxaO9iKybq0fTvqXy8kDc9Wd85rt"
  "from" => "2"
  "from_number" => "10000016"
  "message" => "asdasd"
  "mobile" => "asdasd"
]
```

i want encrypt data when send like this  **wrsa7dagsda76sd67awedtsdfjwerfh78wegfsr67a**  and in controller again use inputes

Comment: Why not make use of the built in [Laravel encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/encryption)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for encryption or decryption (AES-256) ...

```
public function encryption($data,  $method){
        $ciphering = "AES-256-CBC";
        $options = 0;
        $encryption_key = env('AES_ENCRYPT_KEY', 'default');
        $encryption_iv = env('AES_ENCRYPT_IV', 'default');

        


        if($method=='encrypt')
            return openssl_encrypt(json_encode($data), $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv);

        else if($method=='decrypt')
            return json_decode(openssl_decrypt($data, $ciphering, $encryption_key, $options, $encryption_iv));

    }
```

Note: If you want to encode string instead of object, remove function `json_encode` and `json_decode`